# Mongoose / MongoDB find if element in input array is in a schema attribute keyword array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need help trying to figure out how the best way to create a query to search keywords array.

I want to be able to search with array `["work", "hi"]` comparing to an array in schema

`["work", "school"]` and should return this document. Right now I'm using

```
this.resumes.find({
    keywords: {
        $all: term.split(' ')
    }
}).limit(50)
.select('-keywords').exec(function (err, resumes) {});
```

but this only works if both are in the search array are in the schema array. So how can I do a partial match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the `$in` operator would make this easier:

`this.resumes.find({ keywords: { $in: [ "work", "hi" ] } })`

Basically, an `$or` on a single array field.  From the docs:

> $in selects the documents where the field value equals any value in
>   the specified array

Answer (score 0):

```
this.resumes.find({$or: [{keywords: term1}, {keywords: term2}]})
```