# Find a Mongodb document if it contains an element in the array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have a field in a mongodb document which has an array, for example:

```
"tags" : [  "tag", "etc1",  "etc2",  "etc3" ]
```

Is there a way that I can select that document if it contains the element 'etc1'?

If I try using the query:

```
db.coll.find({"tags" : { $elemMatch: { value0: 'etc1'} }})
```

but I need to know the position of the element in the array, which I don't know.

I have also tried:

```
db.coll.find({"tags" : { $elemMatch: 'etc1' }})
```

but it needs to be an object. Is there any way of doing this?

NB I am using mongoose but I wasn't sure how to construct the query

Comment: Please do not post with statements such as "but if it needs to be an object". Please actually show your **real** data and what you actually are trying to do. Change the names to protect the innocent, but show your actual needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `$in` operator as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818303/how-do-i-perform-this-query-in-mongoose-mongodb-for-node-js) or [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295649/mongoose-mongodb-find-if-element-in-input-array-is-in-a-schema-attribute-keywo) and as described in the [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and can be [accessed in mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-in).

With it, you'll have a query that looks something like this...[remembering that you must pass an array when using $in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839765/whats-wrong-with-in-in-mongoose):

`db.coll.find({"tags" : { $in : ['etc1']  } } );`

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using $in operator you can also use $all operator like:

```
db.col1.find({"tags":{$all :["etc1"]}})
```